# Random Audio onmouseover jquery not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, audio, random, onmouseover

I am trying to use jquery to create a random audio effect for all my nav buttons basically the idea is you hover on the unique nav div and a random audio mp3 file from an array is played

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>AAARGH CARIBBEAN PIRATES</title>
          <meta charset = "utf8">
          <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "main.css">
          <script src = "jq/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       </head>
<body>
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <div class = "navmain">
            <div class = "navbox">
                <p class = "navi"><a href = "arms.html">arms</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class = "navbox">
                <p class = "navi"><a href = "map.html">map</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class = "navbox">
                <p class = "navi"><a href = "ship.html">ship</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class = "navbox">
                <p class = "navi"><a href = "facts.html">facts</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class = "navbox">
                <p class = "navi"><a href = "speech.html">speech</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "home">
            <div id = "innerhome">
                <p class = "basic">
                AAARGH mateys, the caribbean was a ..
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.navbox').onmouseover(playSound());
        });

        function playSound(){
            var audio[];
            audio[0] = new Audio("assetts/audio/bird.mp3");
            audio[1] = new Audio("assetts/audio/cannon.mp3");
            audio[2] = new Audio("assetts/audio/fire.mp3");
            audio[3] = new Audio("assetts/audio/monkey.mp3");
            audio[4] = new Audio("assetts/audio/crows.mp3");
            audio[5] = new Audio("assetts/audio/cannon2.mp3");

            var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000) % 6);

            audio[x].play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

it's not working ..not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: When you debug `console.log(audio);`. Do you get an empty array or an array of `HTMLAudioElement` objects?

Comment: I'm new to all this so I mucked about with console.log and my audio message comes up in console but nothing else...anyways I have added the missing brackets to my document ready declaration and now the sound works randomly but only when the page loads or is refreshed not when I mouseover the selected div ...any clues

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the given code.

**HTML**

First of all an advice. You should rebuild your navigation markup to something more common, modern and accessible, like:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navmain">
        <li class="navbox"><a href="arms.html">arms</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a href="map.html">map</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a href="map.html">map</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a href="ship.html">ship</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a href="facts.html">facts</a></li>
        <li class="navbox"><a href="speech.html">speech</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**

Here's the final and working JavaScript part:

```
var current = null;
var audio = [
    new Audio("assetts/audio/bird.mp3"),
    new Audio("assetts/audio/cannon.mp3"),
    new Audio("assetts/audio/fire.mp3"),
    new Audio("assetts/audio/monkey.mp3"),
    new Audio("assetts/audio/crows.mp3"),
    new Audio("assetts/audio/cannon2.mp3")
];

function playSound() {
    if (null !== current) {
        audio[current].pause();
    }

    current = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) % 6);
    audio[current].play();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbox').mouseover(playSound);
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/EEW7E/)

**Some further explanations**

`var audio[];` will not work, like it would for example in C++, where `string audio[6];` is valid. You can however insert all elements like I did on initialization or you can create an empty array like this:

```
var audio = [];
```

The jQuery function is not called `.onmouseover` but [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/). And you can pass in a function name without the braces, like:

```
$('.navbox').mouseover(playSound);
```

or you can create a function, like:

```
$('.navbox').mouseover(function() { playSound(); } );
```

Finally I made the `audio`-array global, that you don't recreate it and all the six audio elements every time the user hovers one of those items and I store the currently playing one in a variable, so that you could stop it, before starting a new sound.

Hope this helps.